# Amend Vector of structs within hashmap in rust. Explicit lifetime annotation in return statement

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(unused_must_use)]
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Product {
    name: String,
    description: Option<String>,
    barcode: String,
    price: String
}


fn main() {

   println!("Loading product list");

   let mut h: HashMap<&str, Vec<Product>> = HashMap::new();
 
   let plastic_bag = Product{ name: "Plastic Bag".to_string(), description: None, barcode: "0001A".to_string(), price: "4.50".to_string() };
   let recyclable_bag = Product{ name: "Recyclable Bag".to_string(), description: None, barcode: "0001B".to_string(), price: "15.50".to_string() };
   
   let category = vec![recyclable_bag, plastic_bag];
   
   h.insert("checkout", category);
   
   println!("{:#?}", h);
   
   let mut h = make_free("checkout", &h);
   
   println!("{:#?}", h);
}

fn make_free<'a>(category: &'a str, checkout_category: &'a mut HashMap<&str, Vec<Product>>) -> &'a mut HashMap<&'a str, Vec<Product>> {
    
    let mut category = checkout_category.get_mut(category).unwrap();
    
    for product in  category {
       product.price = "0.00".to_string();
       println!("{:#?}", product);
   }
   
   return checkout_category
    
}
```

I have a list of pre-defined products filled in. I have a method which I call that I would like to change the prices of the borrowed reference's contents to $0.

I receive the 2 errors:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:31:38
   |
31 |    let mut h = make_free("checkout", &h);
   |                                      ^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::collections::HashMap<&str, std::vec::Vec<Product>>`
                      found reference `&std::collections::HashMap<&str, std::vec::Vec<Product>>`

error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `checkout_category`
  --> src/main.rs:45:11
   |
36 | fn make_free<'a>(category: &'a str, checkout_category: &'a mut HashMap<&str, Vec<Product>>) -> &'a mut HashMap<&'a str, Vec<Product>> {
   |                                                        ----------------------------------- help: add explicit lifetime `'a` to the type of `checkout_category`: `&'a mut std::collections::HashMap<&'a str, std::vec::Vec<Product>>`
...
45 |    return checkout_category
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'a` required
```

I'm really confused on how you can add a lifetime specifier to the return statement, and why the types are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with this code and they all relate to Rust's concept of ownership and shared and mutable references. I recommend reading the [Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) section of the free [The Rust Programming Language book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) or even better the respective sections in "Programming Rust" from O'Reilly.

In summary, the most important rules regarding ownership are as follows:

1. Values have a single owner. Re-assigning a value to a new variable moves the value and makes the perviously owning variable invalid/unusable. Rust tracks this at compile time. When the variable that owns a value goes out of scope the value is dropped (=deleted).
2. There can be many shared references (e.g. `&HashMap<..>`) of a value. When there is one or more shared reference, the value is immutable.
3. Alternatively, there can be one (and only one) mutable reference (e.g. `&mut HashMap<..>`) of a value. When a mutable reference exists no other reference (shared or mutable) can exist. Mutable references are unique.
4. References must never outlive the value they refer to.

(There are ways to bend these rules, but these are the base rules in Rust and important to understand.)

The other part that is confusing in Rust are the differences between `String` and `&str`. Again, I recommend reading more on this, but the gist is

- `String` owns a string value on the heap
- `&str` is a reference to a string that somebody else owns.

Now, looking at the code

```rust
let mut h: HashMap<&str, Vec<Product>> = HashMap::new();
```

This part is a little bit weird (it might be what you wanted, but probably not): the variable `h` owns the `HashMap`, but the `HashMap` does not own its keys, it only has references to them. Per rule (4) `h` must not live longer than any of the keys put into it. In practice, Rust cannot track this, so this hashmap is effectively limited to holding `&str` references that live for the whole program, these are called `&'static str`, the most common are string literals.

To get a `HashMap` which owns its keys (they usual case), you'd use

```rust
let mut h: HashMap<String, Vec<Product>> = HashMap::new();
//                 ^^^^^^-- instead of &str
```

Now the `make_free` function wants to modify the hashmap it receives. There are two idiomatic ways of doing this: (a) take ownership of the hashmap and return a new hashmap or (b) take a mutable reference `&mut HashMap<..>` and modify it in place but don't return anything. In this case using a mutable reference would be more natural:

```rust
fn make_free(category: &str, checkout_category: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<Product>>) {
    
    let mut category = checkout_category.get_mut(category).unwrap();
    
    for product in  category {
       product.price = "0.00".to_string();
       println!("{:#?}", product);
   }
```

Notice that you don't need lifetimes in this case, you only need them when you return a reference (which is rare).

Using `String`s owned by the hashmap and this version of `make_free` the code becomes ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=42f6e09840d894e82cd235395a38b793)):

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(unused_must_use)]
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Product {
    name: String,
    description: Option<String>,
    barcode: String,
    price: String
}


fn main() {
   println!("Loading product list");
   let mut h: HashMap<String, Vec<Product>> = HashMap::new();

   let plastic_bag = Product{ name: "Plastic Bag".to_string(), description: None, barcode: "0001A".to_string(), price: "4.50".to_string() };
   let recyclable_bag = Product{ name: "Recyclable Bag".to_string(), description: None, barcode: "0001B".to_string(), price: "15.50".to_string() };

   let category = vec![recyclable_bag, plastic_bag];
   h.insert("checkout".to_string(), category);
 
   println!("{:#?}", h);
   
   make_free("checkout", &mut h);
   
   println!("{:#?}", h);
}

fn make_free(category: &str, checkout_category: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<Product>>) {
    let mut category = checkout_category.get_mut(category).unwrap();
    
    for product in  category {
       product.price = "0.00".to_string();
       println!("{:#?}", product);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible, definitely a better way to do it! Thank you for the exceptional detail as well!

Answer (score 1):

Ownership and lifetime problems aside, your main issue is that the input parameter is missing the lifetime on the first type argument: you have `HashMap<&str, Vec<Product>>` rather than `HashMap<&'a str, Vec<Product>>` which is the return type. Therefore the inferred lifetime of `checkout_category` is not `'a`, which is required by the method signature. Adding the missing `'a` fixes this.

Next, your function `make_free` takes an `&mut` reference but you borrowed `h` as an `&` reference. This is easily fixed:

```
let mut h = make_free("checkout", &mut h);
```